# Rails3.1.10 + asset compile on local machine gives me an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I am working on a rails 3.1.10 application and have the following error when I execute "rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production"

rake version is 10.1.0 and I can execute rake db:reset without an error.

Many thank in advance

```
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
Application has been already initialized.
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/application.rb:95:in `initialize!'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:91:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary => assets:environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/...]
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:9:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:17:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.10)
      actionpack (= 3.1.10)
      mail (~> 2.3.3)
    actionpack (3.1.10)
      activemodel (= 3.1.10)
      activesupport (= 3.1.10)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.6)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.4)
    activemodel (3.1.10)
      activesupport (= 3.1.10)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.10)
      activemodel (= 3.1.10)
      activesupport (= 3.1.10)
      arel (~> 2.2.3)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activerecord-import (0.3.1)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
    activeresource (3.1.10)
      activemodel (= 3.1.10)
      activesupport (= 3.1.10)
    activesupport (3.1.10)
      multi_json (>= 1.0, < 1.3)
    ansi (1.4.3)
    arel (2.2.3)
    attr_required (0.0.5)
    aws-s3 (0.6.3)
      builder
      mime-types
      xml-simple
    aws-sdk (1.11.1)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.0)
    better_errors (0.9.0)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.0.4)
    callsite (0.0.11)
    capybara (1.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 0.2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    childprocess (0.3.9)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    cloudfront-signer (2.1.0)
    cocaine (0.3.2)
    coderay (1.0.9)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    dalli (2.6.4)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    delayed_job (3.0.5)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
    delayed_job_active_record (0.4.4)
      activerecord (>= 2.1.0, < 4)
      delayed_job (~> 3.0)
    diff-lcs (1.2.4)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    exception_notification (4.0.0)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.4)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.4)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.8.7)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1)
    fb_graph (2.6.0)
      httpclient (>= 2.2.0.2)
      multi_json
      rack-oauth2 (>= 0.14.4)
      tzinfo
    ffi (1.9.0)
    formatador (0.2.4)
    guard (1.8.1)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 1.0.0)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.2)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
      thor (>= 0.14.6)
    guard-rspec (3.0.2)
      guard (>= 1.8)
      rspec (~> 2.13)
    hashie (2.0.5)
    hike (1.2.3)
    httpauth (0.2.0)
    httpclient (2.3.3)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    jpmobile (2.0.11)
    jquery-rails (3.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.0)
    json_pure (1.8.0)
    jsonschema (2.0.2)
    jwt (0.1.6)
      multi_json (>= 1.0)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    kgio (2.8.0)
    listen (1.2.2)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
      rb-kqueue (>= 0.2)
    lumberjack (1.0.4)
    mail (2.3.3)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    meta_request (0.2.7)
      callsite
      rack-contrib
      railties
    method_source (0.8.1)
    mime-types (1.23)
    mini_portile (0.5.1)
    multi_json (1.2.0)
    multipart-post (1.2.0)
    newrelic_rpm (3.6.5.130)
    nokogiri (1.6.0)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    oauth2 (0.8.1)
      faraday (~> 0.8)
      httpauth (~> 0.1)
      jwt (~> 0.1.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    omniauth (1.1.4)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 3)
      rack
    omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.1.0)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
      oauth2 (~> 0.8.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    paperclip (3.0.2)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)
      mime-types
    paypal_adaptive (0.3.6)
      json (~> 1.0)
      jsonschema (~> 2.0.0)
    pg (0.15.1)
    pg_search (0.7.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.1)
      arel
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pry (0.9.12.2)
      coderay (~> 1.0.5)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pusher (0.11.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      signature (~> 0.1.6)
    rack (1.3.10)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-contrib (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.1)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-oauth2 (0.14.8)
      activesupport (>= 2.3)
      attr_required (>= 0.0.5)
      httpclient (>= 2.2.0.2)
      i18n
      json (>= 1.4.3)
      rack (>= 1.1)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.10)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.10)
      actionpack (= 3.1.10)
      activerecord (= 3.1.10)
      activeresource (= 3.1.10)
      activesupport (= 3.1.10)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.10)
    railties (3.1.10)
      actionpack (= 3.1.10)
      activesupport (= 3.1.10)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    raindrops (0.11.0)
    rake (10.1.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.0)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec (2.14.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    rspec-core (2.14.2)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.1)
    rspec-rails (2.14.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.2.9)
    sass-rails (3.1.7)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    selenium-webdriver (0.2.2)
      childprocess (>= 0.1.9)
      ffi (>= 1.0.7)
      json_pure
      rubyzip
    signature (0.1.7)
    slop (3.4.5)
    sprockets (2.0.4)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    thin (1.5.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.7)
    treetop (1.4.14)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turn (0.8.2)
      ansi (>= 1.2.2)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.1.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    unicorn (4.6.3)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    uuidtools (2.1.4)
    xml-simple (1.1.2)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord-import
  aws-s3
  aws-sdk
  bcrypt-ruby
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  capybara (= 1.0.0)
  cloudfront-signer
  cocaine (= 0.3.2)
  coffee-rails (~> 3.1.1)
  dalli
  delayed_job_active_record
  exception_notification (~> 4.0.0.rc1)
  factory_girl_rails
  fb_graph
  guard-rspec
  jpmobile (~> 2.0.5)
  jquery-rails
  kaminari
  meta_request
  newrelic_rpm
  omniauth
  omniauth-facebook
  paperclip (= 3.0.2)
  paypal_adaptive
  pg
  pg_search
  pusher
  rails (= 3.1.10)
  rake
  rb-fsevent (~> 0.9)
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails (~> 3.1.5)
  thin
  turn (= 0.8.2)
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  unicorn
```

Comment: can you try the command `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace`

Comment: Hi G SubbaRao, thank for your reply but I got same error message ;(

Comment: Can You update the output of above command

Comment: Hi G SubbaRao,  I got the following.
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
rake aborted!
Application has been already initialized.

Comment: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/application.rb:95:in `initialize!'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:91:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'